# Strange problem: Not able to input question mark in Chrome, control panel, setting etc, but no problem in ubuntu terminal

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Very strange problem:

1), Not able to input "?" character in most of applications, for example, chrome, vscode.

2), Able to input "?" in ubuntu terminal.

3),

`"showkey -a"`able to detect correct keyboard code.

```
Press any keys - Ctrl-D will terminate this program

?    63 0077 0x3f
?    63 0077 0x3f
```

3), Before one day ago, no different in all applications.

OS: Ubuntu 21.10. Thanks ChanganAuto pointed it out.

Keyboard layout: US keyboard.

No idea how to start trouble shooting, please give some hint. Thank you very much.

[Update 20220308]

I use xev to monitor what happened, then found that there have FocusIn and FocusOut event. Looks like there have other place modified the keycode. See below Log:

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
    root 0x2a6, subw 0x0, time 26707415, (788,689), root:(838,803),
    state 0x10, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  14  0   0   0   0   0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
    root 0x2a6, subw 0x0, time 26709387, (788,689), root:(838,803),
    state 0x11, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I also checked the keymap is correct in xmodmap:

```
keycode  61 = slash question slash question
```

I continue to do the investigation see which window is 0x2000001:

```
 ~  xlsclients -l
Window 0x200001:
  Machine:  xxxxx
  Name:  gsd-xsettings
  Icon Name:  gsd-xsettings
  Command:  gsd-xsettings
  Instance/Class:  gsd-xsettings/Gsd-xsettings
```

And this is prove why this symptoms not happen on terminal.

Then remove ulauncher the problem fixed.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 is out of support. Please install a supported release.

Comment: Sorry, my miss typing. It's 21.10:

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, you can report a bug https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#:~:text=To%20file%20a%20bug%20against,the%20%E2%80%9CRun%20Command%E2%80%9D%20screen.